# Swift Animation behaves weird after changing Label

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, ios-animations

I am currently working on an animation for my ios application. When it gets triggered three blocks (UIView with borders) move down and a new block comes in from the left.

[image: Working Version]

It works perfectly until I change the text of the label (Block Number) before the animation starts. The blocks spawn in completely different positions and move back to the start position. They also change their order.

[image]

The following code shows my block class. For the animation I use the getBlockView and "view.frame = GCRect(...)". For changing the label text I use the setBlockName(number: String) function.

At the moment I don´t have any idea what could cause that and would be thankful for every suggestion what could cause this weird behaviour.

```
class myBlock {
        var positionID: Int
        var blockNumber: String
        let blockView: UIView
        let blockNumberLabel: UILabel

        init(blockNumber: String, heightScreen: CGFloat, widthScreen: CGFloat, positionID: Int) {
            self.positionID = positionID
            self.blockNumber = blockNumber
            blockView = {
                let view = UIView()
                view.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: heightScreen / 6)
                view.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: widthScreen - 80)
                view.layer.borderWidth = 3
                view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.MyTheme.primaryColor1.cgColor
                return view
            }()
            blockNumberLabel = {
                let label = UILabel()
                label.textColor = UIColor.MyTheme.primaryColor1
                label.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
                label.numberOfLines = 2
                label.textAlignment = .left
                label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
                label.text = "Block Number: \(blockNumber)"
                label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                return label
            }()

            blockView.addSubview(blockNumberLabel)
            blockNumberLabel.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top, withInset: 5.0)
            blockNumberLabel.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left, withInset: 5.0)
            blockNumberLabel.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right, withInset: 5.0)

        }

        func getBlockView() -> UIView{
            return blockView
        }

        func setBlockName(number: String) {
            self.blockNumberLabel.text = "Block Number: \(number)"
        }

        func getBlockLabel() -> UILabel{
            return blockNumberLabel
        }

        func getID() -> Int {
            return positionID
        }

        func setID(id: Int) {
            self.positionID = id
            print("\(blockNumberLabel.text!): \(id)")
        }

    }
```

Animation Code:

```
   private func moveBlocksDown(blockNumber: String) {
    var resetBlock: UIView!
    let animationHeight =  (self.heightScreen / 6) + (self.blockDistance)



    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
        for var block in self.blockList {
            let id = block.getID()
            let blockView = block.getBlockView()
            if block.getID() == 0 {
                 block.setBlockName(number: blockNumber)
            }
            print(id)
            switch id {
            case 0:
                blockView.frame = CGRect(x: self.topX, y: self.topY, width: blockView.frame.width, height: blockView.frame.height)
                print(block.getBlockLabel().text!)
            case 1:
                blockView.frame = CGRect(x: self.topX, y: self.middleY, width: blockView.frame.width, height: blockView.frame.height)
                print(block.getBlockLabel().text!)
            case 2:
                blockView.frame = CGRect(x: self.topX, y: self.bottomY, width: blockView.frame.width, height: blockView.frame.height)
                print(block.getBlockLabel().text!)
            case 3:
                blockView.frame = CGRect(x: self.topX, y: (self.bottomY + animationHeight), width: blockView.frame.width, height: blockView.frame.height)
                print(block.getBlockLabel().text!)
                resetBlock = blockView
            default:
                print("Unknown ID")
            }
            print("NewID \((id + 1) % 4)")
            block.setID(id: (id + 1) % 4)
        }
    }, completion: { finish in  
       resetBlock.frame = CGRect(x: self.newX, y: self.newY, width: resetBlock.frame.width, height: resetBlock.frame.height)


    })


}
```

Comment: show the animation code to, this is more likely the issue

Comment: I added the animation code.